# Dropdown selector with no options. Disabled or not?

Tags: guidelines

I have a dropdown HTML select menu. Entries will appear once a calculation is performed, however until then, there is nothing available, and therefore the dropdown is empty. The dropdown should be there because it will make clear that the output area is available, but nothing has been calculated.

My concern is about the state of the dropdown. I don't recall any similar situation anywhere, and neither the macOS or the Windows HIG specify what should be done in this case. Should the select be empty, but selectable (eventually showing an empty dropdown menu) or should the control be disabled altogether?

Comment: Would you have a screenshot you could share?

Answer (score 1):

You're right in that it needs to be made clear that the output is pending calculation, but it doesn't necessarily mean that the dropdown needs to be there. This can be accomplished via other means, e.g. by a text instructing the user to perform the calculation (or just to wait in case no action is necessary), although a better alternative would be a dedicated empty state. You can get some ideas from [emptystat.es](https://emptystat.es/).

In any case, if you encounter a dropdown with no values, the best option is to try to avoid it altogether. If that's not possible, it should be disabled so as to prevent the user from opening it and realizing they walked into a cul-de-sac. This would be the equivalent of a "Dead end" sign on the road leading into it.

Comment: thank you for that link. I didn't know about it. Very precious stuff.